# Circular dependency between modules 'Realm' and 'RealmSwift' error in Swift

Tags: swift, realm, cocoapods

I installed RealmSwift via Cocoapod. Even though I did not add Realm (Objective-C version) frame work to the Podfile, it still installed Realm with RealmSwift. When I imported RealmSwift, it gave me an error like this:

> Circular dependency between modules 'Realm' and 'RealmSwift'.

Why does this happen and what do I need to get rid of this dumb error?

Comment: If you install the RealmSwift pod it will automatically include the installation of the Realm pod. I would suggest performing a clean on the project and then rebuilding it just in case there is something in there that's causing the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your pod file in it and also describe how you import RealmSwift, since you shouldn't do any manual imports, cocoapods will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can occur if the project has the same name as another module. I once named a new project `CoreGraphics` because that was the subject of what I was learning. This obviously conflicted with the `CoreGraphics` library from Apple. I started again with a nw project name and problem went away.